# Prevent numpy object array from casting elements

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I am trying to construct a numpy array of pandas MultiIndexes. The array has dtype='object' and each element of the array should be a pd.MultiIndex.

Here's an example:

```
a  = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([pd.RangeIndex(3), pd.RangeIndex(2)])
b  = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([pd.RangeIndex(3), pd.RangeIndex(2)])
array = np.array([a,b], dtype='object')
```

The output is:

```
array([[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1)],
       [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1)]], dtype=object)
```

What i would like the output to be:

```
array([MultiIndex([(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1)]),
       MultiIndex([(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1)])], dtype=object)
```

I would assume that specifying dtype='object' when creating the array would prevent numpy from casting the input to some other python type, but apparently it is casting my multiindexes into list. How do i stop it from casting?

Thanks!

Comment: why not just use a list `[a,b]`?  What does object array do for you?

Comment: I need the array because i need to use a lot of numpy-specific tools on it, like flatten and reshape. This array is used to construct another 'real' numpy array. If i could use a normal list I would, believe me.

Comment: what's `array.shape`?

Comment: That will depend on the input data. Could be as easy as `(1,)`. But it might also be `(30,30,20)`

Comment: I wanted the shape of the actual array you show, I was puzzled by the tuples in what looks like a (2,6) array.  Why wasn't it (2,6,2).  Turns out `a.values` is a 1d object dtype array of tuples.  If they differed in length it would keep them separate, but since they match it can make a 2d array instad.  That's normal `np.array` behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.empty` to create an empty array of the desired shape and then copy the data to the array:

```py
lst = [a, b]
array = np.empty(len(lst), dtype=object)
array[:] = lst[:]
```

```
[MultiIndex([(0, 0),
             (0, 1),
             (1, 0),
             (1, 1),
             (2, 0),
             (2, 1)],
            )         MultiIndex([(0, 0),
                                  (0, 1),
                                  (1, 0),
                                  (1, 1),
                                  (2, 0),
                                  (2, 1)],
                                 )        ]
```